# Facebook Graph API and Insights not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I simply want to pull insight data for my company utilizing the Facebook Graph API.  I am testing using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

When I enter `https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ID/insights?` and an Access Token I would expect to see JSON data with such data as `Page_Views`.  However I only see this:

```
{
      "data": [
      ],
      "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ID/insights?format=json&since=1337268417&until=1337527617",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ID/insights?format=json&since=1337786817&until=1338046017"
      }
}
```

Any suggestions on the URL or perhaps I shouldn't be using Graph API to view Page_Views?

Comment: what kind of access token? app or user? if user, did you request the `read_insights` permission?

Comment: From my knowledge I am supposed to provide any APP access token, so I have provided APP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Page object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page), for the `insights` connection:

> **Permissions:** A valid access_token with read_insights permission for a user
>   authorized to view the Page's insights

In the explorer click the `Get Access Token` button, change to the "Extended Permissions" tab and check the "read_insights" box, then click the button and try again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might run into this issue that wants to view a 'Page' nstead of a user in say v2.4 you might need to use 'Get Page Token' in the 'Get Token' field otherwise you could be seeing what ToddN saw

Comment: Same thing, user or page token return empty data